# Is it reasonable to assume the near-extinction of women?

Tags: psychology, genetics, social-norms, reincarnation, eugenics

The world of Ruquelis has some problems.  It is populated by men, women and winged lilim as in this question: [How to get the Lilim to breed true?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/236068/75).  People on Ruquelis reincarnate according to the mechanism I describe in this question: [Is it reasonable that a nation reject reincarnation?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/233825/75).

Ruquelis has some pretty distasteful customs, including the mass removal of girls who do not become lilim by their ninth birthday from the gene pool, by execution, forced sterilization and/or cannibalism, that have been reinforced by reincarnation.  Part of these problems have been compounded by a drug, *hialutabu*, which makes its users experience pain as pleasure, which is administered to the girls or women to be disposed of in order that their next incarnations remember the experience in a positive light.

The worst part of this systemic prejudice against women is that children born on Ruquelis are raised to believe that women have no value as parents, that their only value is for what they can learn before their deaths and reincarnation, and perhaps for the value of their flesh for the meat trade, and that their deaths are both a positive personal experience that will be remembered by their next incarnation and a positive contribution to their society.

These customs arose as a response to the birth ratios of breeding between men and women, and men and lilim: all offspring of women are 1/2 men, 1/2 women, while the offspring of lilim are 1/3 men, 1/3 women and 1/3 lilim, and have a slightly lower birth rate than women due to 1/4 of fertilized ova being non-viable.  Going by pure mathematics, this would appear to be a recipe for the extinction of lilim.

I am considering the implications of an outside party genetically altering all lilim so that instead of the birth ratio described above, lilim bear 50% men, 50% lilim children, and half of their fertilized ova are non-viable.  This would be done in an attempt to eliminate the Ruquelians' vile and murderous customs.

Is it reasonable to assume that in a Ruquelian society with reincarnation reinforcing tradition, that such a change would result in a drastic crash in the population of women that might result in their extinction, or would the value of women as the only source of new women increase, leading to their being allowed to reproduce in order to provide new woman-children who could be used to continue the Ruquelian traditions?

Further, if the value of women rises as their population falls in the areas with a tradition of cannibalism, is it reasonable to assume that the traditions of killing, sterilizing or cannibalizing them will abate as it becomes too expensive to continue them?

Comment: I'm unclear on the question.  Given that under the "genetically altered" conditions then all women within reach of the psycho society die and only men and lilim are born.  So trivially yes, all women are extinct ("murdered" is a better word) as soon as the specified conditions are implemented.  Are you now asking whether once women are almost gone that the men and lilim are going to miss them?  That's entirely up to you as the author, it's storytelling!  (If the question is whether the population is sustainable, we need more information on mortality and reproduction rates, not ratios.)

Answer (score 6):

#### Purpose-bred women would remain as livestock only

A society that has come to the conclusion that

> their deaths are a positive contribution to their society

isn't going to see the continuation of women as a "breed" as a desirable thing in itself; and none of the other "uses" of women (reincarnation, breeding) are women-specific, so the only reason to keep them around would be as a delicacy for men and lilim who have developed a taste for human flesh. I can definitely see the more "enlightened" members of society (relatively speaking) taking the position that is it better, and more humane, to let women go extinct, like some animals' rights groups argue in our society regarding domesticated animals; to keep breeding women would end up being, counterintuitively, the more reactionary opinion, driven by traditionalists, cannibals and perhaps fetishists.

#### Naturally born women may be treated quite differently

Depending on how you decide to implement your genetic rebalancing system, you may end up with a situation where some % of progeny from a man x lilim pregnancy is a woman. Up until now, lilim knew that half their daughters were going to be destined for the roasting tin, and must have behaved and prepared themselves accordingly (not sure how, this setup is utterly horrific). Now, however, woman daughters are quite rare and unexpected. Parents may allow themselves to grow attached to their daughters assuming that they're *almost certainly* going to develop as lilim. What happens once they reach the age of 9 and they don't grow talons?

Some parents may be horrified and do all they can to get rid of this undesirable, shameful, defective daughter. But others may refuse to let her be sacrificed, having spent many years bonding with her as a human being deserving of a future. Girls who have grown with the expectation of a full life (because the vast majority of children are either boys or lilim, so there's less need for the societal indoctrination that would have made them sufficiently pliant and accepting of the ninth birthday culling) may be more inclined to try their luck by running away to join communities of escaped women; their parents (some parents) may help them accomplish this. Age 9 is pretty young, but over time a network would form supporting these runaway girls.

The obvious caveat is chromosomal screening: if you don't have to wait until age 9 to tell that a daughter is a woman, then you'd just get selective abortions. But if so, your premise (of waiting until the ninth birthday to sacrifice the girls) doesn't quite work either.

Comment: A note that is narrative enough that I think is best as a comment: depending on how you implement this, you are bound to risk mirroring various examples of real-life discrimination (e.g. racism/enslavement, rejection of LGBT+ children by parents, etc.). Even if you *don't* intend your story to be a parable on intolerance, it may end up reading as such, and therefore your implications will appear as commentary on the real-world issue your world appears to mirror. Just be mindful of your own position, and perhaps ask for opinions from others with different perspectives.

Comment: The thing is, the world of Ersutiabu also has lilim, but there, reincarnation anchors are forbidden, and women have equal rights to men and almost equal to lilim, including reproductive rights.  It is entirely possible for woman-children to flee to Ersutiabu... if they can overcome their conditioning and anti-Ersutiaban propaganda.

Comment: Another thing is that on Ruquelis, where cannibalism is practised, most women aren't eaten until their late teens or early twenties, and until then, their duty is to learn in order to provide the greatest possible advantage to their next incarnation.  They often aren't sterilized either, since a pregnant woman has a higher value as a meat animal.

Comment: As to how women can be raised to accept being murdered, that's due to hialutabu.  That drug makes the women who are murdered enjoy the experience, and their next incarnation remembers that death as a positive experience.

Comment: If women themselves look forward to death, why would they wait to be murdered instead of just taking their own lives as soon as they can? Being reincarnated as a man or lilim seems desirable to a life as a subjugated subhuman. Yes, you say they have a "duty" to learn, but people, understandably, rebel against a duty imposed by others for others' benefit.

Comment: True... but access to hialutabu, which is what makes the experience 'positive', is highly restricted due to its addictive and harmful potential.  It is effectively restricted to those who are about to die, be they women to be eliminated, or soldiers on suicide missions.

Comment: Besides, consider other IRL traditions around the world that are repugnant to most of us... female circumcision, sati, honour killings and the like.  They haven't all died out despite their negative impact on their victims and efforts to stamp out those practises.  Tradition can be really hard to break.

Answer (score 4):

## Reincarnation is gonna make rich men want to keep harems.

You have reincarnation, where people can regenerate with their memories somewhat intact. Many of those people will likely be wealthy men who are somewhat heterosexual, and who want to sleep with women. As such, they would make active efforts to preserve the population of women against any tradition.

## Smarter women are gonna rebel and form societies away from the mainstream.

Your society sounds horrible to live in, a hellish dystopia that most would hate. A lot of people are gonna leave and live away from the mainstream in remote areas or other kingdoms.

Answer (score 3):

**The social desirability of lilim will diminish**

As you said:

> These customs arose as a response to the birth ratios of breeding between men and women, and men and lilim: all offspring of women are 1/2 men, 1/2 women, while the offspring of lilim are 1/3 men, 1/3 women and 1/3 lilim, and have a slightly lower birth rate than women due to 1/4 of fertilized ova being non-viable. Going by pure mathematics, this would appear to be a recipe for the extinction of lilim.

So lilim are socially exalted over women because they are rare. But as you have set things up, lilim are gonna become super common. Indeed women are going to become rare.

So why would these customs continue? Further wouldn't genetic modification of lilim mean that you have a dichotomy between altered lilim and "natural" lilim, with the latter being more prized?

Answer (score 1):

If 50% of the fertilized ova are not viable, instead of 1/4, then per fertilization the lilim give birth to 25% men, 25% lilim, and have 50% miscarriages. I fail to see why this is better than 25% miscarriages, 25% men, 25% lilim, and 25% women, as it stands. Unless the point was to just stop giving birth to women. If this society wants women to go extinct, they can just kill them at birth, or abort babies in the womb as soon as the sex is determined.

The same could be said if the women are considered breeders for men; per fertilization of a women (which happens more often) half are men, half are women, and other than her own replacement female (to keep the women population stable), the female fetii could be aborted quickly, so the women can recover and be re-impregnated to try again. If men are valued, the women have value for making more males, and replacing themselves.

If the women are allowed to produce more than one female child, then you can still "harvest" women for sacrifice or economics at young ages as a process of selective breeding, like we do with livestock.

I'd worry, if I were writing this, that even if it was my original idea I might be seen by agents and publishers to be writing a knock-off of The Handmaid's Tale. It sounds similarly oppressive, to me.

Comment: The goal is to prevent *lilim* from going extinct.  With half of the female offspring of a lilim being unable to give birth to a lilim, naive mathematics suggests that unless drastic measures are taken, lilim will become extinct.  However, Ersutiabu has already proven this to be false.  However, the Ruquelians would prefer that lilim not give birth to women at all.

Comment: Also, the tech level of the society doesn't allow early discrimination between women and lilim at a reasonable cost.  Only the fabulously wealthy could afford to screen a child at birth.